# How can I create my own data type with 16+ significant digits?

Tags: c#, types

i need own datatype for my work like double with 16 digits after  decimal point . what can i do for that.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the **[`System.Decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28VS.80%29.aspx)** data type? It has about 28 significant digits of precision.